# I am not able to compare my password with md5 database password

Tags: php, md5

I am trying to compare my login password with database md5 password but not able to do it.I have also made my login password using md5 but still the problem occour.. please help me out i am new in PHP.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$pass =md5($password);
if ($username&&$password)
{
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pixster")or die("Couldn't connect to database!");
mysqli_select_db($connect,'rdb') or die ("Couldn't find database");
echo "successfully connected to database<br>";
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE uname ='$username'");
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!==0)
{
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
   $dbusername = $row['uname'];
   $dbpassword = $row['password'];
   $dbusername;
   $dbpassword;
   }

    if($username==$dbusername&& $pass==$dbpassword)
    {
       include('logprofile.php');
       echo "you are logged in!";
       //$_SESSION['abc'] = $username;


    }else

    echo "your password is wrong";
```

Comment: md5 is no longer a secure encryption for storing passwords

Comment: Did you post your real root password in the db connect???

Comment: plz tell what the actual problem you face what type of error you get?

Comment: @Misunderstood Yes, he did. But it doesn't matter because you can't access his root anyway. It's local.

Comment: yes i am able to connect with my database..

Comment: this post is a bit incomplete. you should also check the data from the database if it's exactly the same

Comment: if($numrows!==0) problem is here you use if($numrows!=0)

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but to you password hashinh algorithm, but please read the following on hashing passwords with md5: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function

Comment: @satish ....i have inserted data in my database using md5 encrypted password..now i want to use login form so i need to compare form password with the database encrypted password.if i use simple password than i am able to do it perfectly..but not with encrypted password???

Comment: @Misunderstood I don't understand you? Anyway, it's not safe the way he did it, but it doesn't matter now, is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this question. there was a database problem my password length was short than the md5 converted password.so i just increased the length. and now both the password are matching and i am able to login.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `if($numrows!=0)` instead of `if($numrows!==0)`

Comment: as a matter of fact the if statement wont be necessary. you can write the while statement instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
       {
       $dbusername = $row['uname'];
       $dbpassword = $row['password'];
       }
```

Remove following lines in loop:

```
 $dbusername;
 $dbpassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$pass =md5($password);
if ($username&&$password)
{
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pixster")or die("Couldn't connect to database!");
mysqli_select_db($connect,'rdb') or die ("Couldn't find database");
echo "successfully connected to database<br>";
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE uname ='$username'");
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows > 0)
{
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
   $dbusername = $row['uname'];
   $dbpassword = $row['password'];
   }

    if($username==$dbusername && $pass==$dbpassword)
    {
       include('logprofile.php');
       echo "you are logged in!";
       //$_SESSION['abc'] = $username;


    }else

    echo "your password is wrong";
```